# reverse typeof(T) to use type in tests

Tags: c#, types, mstest

I have a factory method `Create<T>()` which returns an instance of a given interface type `T`. The Factory pattern works, but now I have to write test in MSTest for our Factory. The tests should check if the instance of our create method is the right one. Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(typeof(Member), typeof(MemberImpl))]
public void Test1(Type interfaceType, Type implType)
{
    implType instance = PlanungContribution.Create<interfaceType>();
}
```

The problem is, that the `DataRow` can only have a `typeof(T)` and not `T` as a parameter. So I have to revert the `typeof(T)` operator.

How can I achieve this?
Is there a better way to do something like this?

**[EDIT]**

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(typeof(Mitarbeiter), typeof(MitarbeiterImpl))]
public void Test1(Type interfaceType, Type baseType)
{
    var t = typeof(ModelContributionPlanungEF6).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType).Invoke(PlanungContribution, new object[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(baseType, t);
}
```

`Assert.AreEqual` failed, because they are not the same. Look closely:

> Message: Assert.AreEqual failed.
>
> Expected: DP.PMS.EF6.Planung.MitarbeiterImpl (System.RuntimeType).
>
> Actual:DP.PMS.EF6.Planung.MitarbeiterImpl
>   (DP.PMS.EF6.Planung.MitarbeiterImpl).

Comment: `PlanungContribution.Create<interfaceType>().GetType()`

Comment: @Will nice way, but I cannot use **interfaceType** this way.

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface anyhow, so what the heck are you trying to do?

Comment: @Will I dont want to instanciate an interface. I want to get an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reflection to achieve this :

```
typeof(PlanungContribution).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType)
    .Invoke(null /*Instance to call on , if static pass null */, new object[0]);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I make an edit to my question, because i have some troubles.

Comment: @PatrikSchweigl What trouble ? Have you tried the reflection way of doing it ?

Comment: @PatrikSchweigl The `Create` method return an instance of your class, you need the type .. `Assert.AreEqual(baseType, t.GetType());`

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke the generic method via reflection first and invoke it. Afterwards check the returned type:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(typeof(Member), typeof(MemberImpl))]
public void Test1(Type interfaceType, Type implType)
{
    var method = typeof(PlanungContribution).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType);
    var instance = method.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    var type = instance.GetType();
    Assert.AreEqual(type, implType);
}
```

Comment: `Create<interfaceType>` won't compile, you need to use reflection to invoke it dynamically.